# How to determine if records (for a certain set) follow a correct order?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that contains 3 different status'

```
1. CLICKED
2. CLAIMED
3. BOUGHT
```

In this particular order. I am trying to determine if there were any records that did not occur in the right order based on their date.

For example, this is the data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2APY8.png)

```
Record 121144 has correct order status, this is good.
Record 121200 is incorrect since bought happens before clicked even if clicked and claimed follow the right order.
Record 121122 is incorrect, since CLICKED status comes after CLAIMED.
Record 121111 also has correct order status (even if they are the same).
Record 121198 is also correct since the status order follows, even if there is no BOUGHT.
```

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_A 
(
    number_id int, 
    country varchar(50), 
    status varchar(50), 
    datetime date
);

INSERT INTO TBL_A 
VALUES (121144, 'USA', 'CLICKED', '2021-10-09'),
       (121144, 'USA', 'CLAIMED', '2021-10-10'),
       (121144, 'USA', 'BOUGHT', '2021-10-11'),
       (121111, 'CAD', 'CLICKED', '2021-10-12'),
       (121111, 'CAD', 'CLAIMED', '2021-10-12'),
       (121111, 'CAD', 'BOUGHT', '2021-10-12'),
       (121122, 'PES', 'CLICKED', '2021-09-11'),
       (121122, 'PES', 'CLAIMED', '2021-09-09'),
       (121122, 'PES', 'BOUGHT', '2021-09-12'),
       (121198, 'AU', 'CLICKED', '2021-09-11'),
       (121198, 'AU', 'CLAIMED', '2021-09-12'),
       (121200, 'POR', 'CLICKED', '2021-09-10'),
       (121200, 'POR', 'CLAIMED', '2021-09-11'),
       (121200, 'POR', 'BOUGHT', '2021-09-08');
```

Comment: What about records with same Id, country and same date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ARRAY_AGG ordered by datetime:

```
SELECT number_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(status) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY datetime) AS statuses, -- debug
    CASE WHEN ARRAY_AGG(status) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY datetime) 
         IN (ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('CLICKED', 'CLAIMED', 'BOUGHT'),
             ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('CLICKED', 'CLAIMED')) THEN 'In order'
         ELSE 'Out of order'
    END AS status
FROM TBL_A
GROUP BY number_id;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My answer includes the potential for skipped steps which OP mentioned in comments. Rather than using a strictly matching sequence this approach looks for adjacent pairs where the preceding step was numbered higher:

```
with A as (
    select *,        
        case status
            when 'CLICKED' then 1
            when 'CLAIMED' then 2
            when 'BOUGHT'  then 3 end as desired_order
    from T
), B as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by number_id
            order by datetime, desired_order) as rn -- handles date ties
    from A
), C as (
    select *,
        -- look for pairs of rows where one is reversed
        case when lag(desired_order) over (partition by number_id order by rn) >
            desired_order then 'Y' end as flag
    from B
)
select number_id, min(country) as country,
    case min(flag) when 'Y' then 'Out of order' else 'In order' end as "status"
from C
group by number_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f0ee1de8e8e81229ddc23acc97bce7d7

As Thorston pointed out, you could also take the approach of generating a pair of row numbers and then comparing the two looking for mismatches. Glancing at the query plans this may involve an extra sort operation so it would be worth trying both ways on your data.

```
...
), B as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by number_id
            order by desired_order) as rn1,
        row_number() over (
            partition by number_id
            order by datetime, desired_order) as rn2
    from A
)
select
  number_id, min(country) as country,
  case when max(case when rn1 <> rn2 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    then 'Out of order' else 'In order' end as status
...
```

Comment: This is a very clean approach that I like very much. You can save one step, though, by using two row numbers, one for the desired order, one for the existing order. See the altered query below yours in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3833e2e4af91154d2d009cec95cbb60e

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten, I think that's basically the solution I had in my head as worked on it. For some reason I got halfway through and started thinking it wouldn't actually work.

Comment: thank you both for your help! This helped so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using some string aggregation and manipulations. This works as expected against the sample data and also accounts for edge cases that include skipping status, missing status, and single status.

```
with cte as

(select *,listagg(status,'>') within group (order by datetime,charindex(status,'CLICKED>CLAIMED>BOUGHT')) over (partition by number_id, country) as event_order
from t)

select distinct 
       number_id,
       country, 
       case when charindex(event_order,'CLICKED>CLAIMED>BOUGHT,CLICKED>BOUGHT')>0 then 'Ordered' else 'Unordered' end as order_flag
from cte
order by number_id;
```

Comment: I think you need to also order on the case expression so that ties in the date will be handled correctly. And then I believe that results should be aggregated for the entire id.

Comment: Hi there! how would I take into account when the status' are missing? If there is only 'claimed' status, then it should also be considered 'ordered'. Not always going to have all three status.

Comment: hi @shawnt00, do you know how I can aggregate for the id?

Comment: @lalaland Try now

Comment: @shawnt00 Good call on the ties